# Importing styles in Next throws an error following basic use examples

Tags: next.js

Following the really basic usage guide on the [npm package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zeit/next-sass) for using Sass I get the following error:

```
./assets/styles.scss
ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
```

I've also tried this with `next-less` (using Ant Design) and the basic `next-css` package, but the results are the same.

```
./assets/styles.less
ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
```

next.config.js

```
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less');

module.exports = withLess();
```

I've also tried the Sass plugin as well

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');

module.exports = withSass({
    cssModules: true
});
```

So are these broken? I can't find any workarounds.

Comment: you should show your `next.config.js` file

Comment: Added the next config. Like I said, for now I am just trying to get the basic examples to work.

Comment: https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/392